# Online directory for investment advisors/financial planners in Canada?

Tags: canada, online-tools, financial-advisor

Where can one find a good directory of investment advisors/financial planners in Canada?

We have Auto Trader, and Renter's News publications, yet I've never seen anything related to money.  Are there web sites for this?

(I would specifically be interested in advisors in the Toronto, Canada area.)

Answer (score 2):

The [Financial Consumer Agency of Canada (FCAC)](http://www.fcac-acfc.gc.ca/eng/index-eng.asp) has a page specifically about [working with a financial planner or advisor](http://www.fcac-acfc.gc.ca/eng/consumers/typesinvest/advisor/index-eng.asp). It's a good starting point if you are thinking about getting a financial professional to help you plan and manage your investments.

In the "Where To Look" section on that page, FCAC refers to a handful of industry associations. I'll specifically highlight the [Financial Planning Standards Council's "Find a planner" page](https://www.fpsc.ca/find-planner), which can help you locate a Certified Financial Planner (CFP).

**Choose financial advice carefully.**  Prefer certified professionals who charge a set fee for service over advisors who work on commission to push investment products.  Commission-based advice is seldom unbiased.

MoneySense magazine published a listing last year for [where to find a fee-only financial planner](http://www.moneysense.ca/2012/10/01/where-to-find-a-fee-only-financial-planner/), calling it *"The most comprehensive listing of Canadian fee-only financial planners on the web"* — but do note the caveat (near the bottom of the page) that the individuals & firms have not been screened.  Do your own due diligence and check references.

Answer (score 1):

[NAPFA](http://napfa.org) claims to have members in Canada. They are an organization of fee-only financial planners--they work for hourly fees, not commissions, so they have no conflicts of interest when giving advice.

Comment: Interestingly, while it [does appear that NAPFA has *some* Canadian members](http://napfa.org/market/faq.asp#FAQ59), there aren't that many.  I found a list of "international" advisors [here](http://www.napfa.org/consumer/planners/internationalAdvisors.asp) and that list currently only shows advisors in Alberta and B.C.  NAPFA's *"Find an advisor"* tool didn't show any advisors near Toronto actually *in* Canada (results were NY, OH, MI.) I've added an answer which provides additional resources for Canadians.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the organizations that financial advisors belong to have a function to find their members. The major ones are listed below:

**Advocis** seems to be the largest organization, with CFPs (Certified Financial Planners) and some Insurance designations. The Advocis advisor search feature can be found [here](http://www.advocis.ca/account/find-ad-form.aspx).

**FPSC** is another organization that has a search for CFPs. Many of the same CFPs are in the Advocis database, but some aren't. The FPSC advisor search feature can be found [here](http://www.fpsc.ca/find-cfp).

**IAFP** is an organization of Registered Financial Planners (RFP). The database is smaller but the designation comes with prestige and is meant to be a mark of quality. The IAFP advisor search feature can be found [here](http://www.iafp.ca/findaplanner_detailed.php).

Finally, there is a site — *full disclosure, I am affiliated with it* — called [wealthprep.ca](http://www.wealthprep.ca) that has a large listing of advisors in Canada. You can filter by profession, specialties, and compensation type and there are ratings and reviews. Here is the page specifically for [Toronto Financial Advisors](http://www.wealthprep.ca/toronto-on-financial-advisors).

Comment: Hi Shawn. Welcome to the site, and thanks for following our affiliation disclosure policy. With respect to the links you couldn't directly post, I've fixed them. You'll be able to post additional links in answers when you attain sufficient [reputation](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). Please have a look around, perhaps ask/answer other questions -- but please remain mindful of and avoid [excessive self-promotion](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Thanks!